# Python : Get items of one attribute (by value) in Json files

Tags: python, json

I'd like to extract all the values of json file. 
For example I have this object, I'd like to get all the "text" values. 
How can I do that ?

```
  list= [
    {
    "text": "contact solution - COUPON",
    "listId": "1",
    "id": "4",
    "leaf": "true" 
    },
    {
    "text": "Falafel (bulk)",
    "listId": "1",
    "id": "161",
    "leaf": "true" 
    },
    {
    "text": "brita filters",
    "listId": "1",
    "id": "166",
    "leaf": "false" 
    }
```

Output:

```
listText = ["contact solution - COUPON","Falafel (bulk)","brita filters"]
```

**UPDATE:**

I am getting these data from a CSV file.

```
text,listId,id,leaf, jsonfile
"1","is","an","example","{ "text": "contact solution - COUPON", "listId": "1", "id": "4","leaf": "true"}"
"2","is","an","example"," { "text": "Falafel (bulk)","listId": "1", "id": "161", "leaf": "true"  }"
"3","is","an","example"," { "text": "Falafel (bulk)","listId": "1","id": "161","leaf": "true" }"
"4","is","an","example"," { "text": "brita filters","listId": "1","id": "166","leaf":"false" }"
"5","is","an","example"
"6","is","an","example"
"7","is","an","example"
```

using Pandas, I am turning column's items to a list.

```
with open("data/output.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    addData = df.Address
        listfiels= df.jsonfile
```

Now, I want to get a list of "text" in the Json file to store it the other json file this way.
I need the YYY list, to select XXX every time.

```
output = [  {
            "type": "User",
            "name": {
                "status": "Single",
                "adress":coordinates
                "details": XXXX }
            }
          for da,coordinates in zip(textData, addData,YYYY )]
```

Does this make sens 
I made this using JS without problems.

```
 var globalData = data.map(function(d) {
            return JSON.parse(d.Jsonfile);
        });
```

I can access to text field without problems.

UPDATE2:
j = json.loads(listfiels[0])
print(j['text'])

I can print successfully  : "contact solution - COUPON"

Answer (score 6):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [
...     {
...         "text": "contact solution - COUPON",
...         "listId": "1",
...         "id": "4",
...         "leaf": "true" 
...     },
...     {
...         "text": "Falafel (bulk)",
...         "listId": "1",
...         "id": "161",
...         "leaf": "true" 
...     },
...     {
...         "text": "brita filters",
...         "listId": "1",
...         "id": "166",
...         "leaf": "false" 
...     }
... ]
>>> [d['text'] for d in lst]
['contact solution - COUPON', 'Falafel (bulk)', 'brita filters']
```

Using `map` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter('text'), lst)) # Omit `list` in Python 2.x
['contact solution - COUPON', 'Falafel (bulk)', 'brita filters']
```

Comment: I got this error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @user3001937, Does your file contain `list=..` literally?

Comment: No ! but I am extracting this list from CSV file. making a list of column's items.

Comment: May be you have variable name list. Try renaming that to lst

Comment: @user3001937, Please update your question with actual content of the file (or upload the file somewhere, and let us know the url)

Comment: @Archit Jain: Check UPDATE2, which is related directly to the message I am getting.

Comment: @user3001937, The csv file is broken. `"` should be escaped.

Comment: @user3001937, JSON text itself is okay, but it should be escaped to put in csv. CSV reader will not get the original JSON text back. Try `print(df)`.

Comment: See the second UPDATE, I am getting results by printing one specific file (using an index).

Comment: @user3001937, The code is accesing `text` field, not `jsonfile` field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46630/discussion-between-user3001937-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 3):

```
   jsonString=open("file.json").read()
   import json
   myList = [e['text'] for e in json.loads(jsonString)]
```